# I'm checking for stack emptiness and still getting this error

Tags: c++, stack

Im getting Line 171: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:180:16

even though I'm checking for stack emptiness before I do anything with a stack, this is largest rectangle in histogram on leetcode btw

```
class Solution {
public:
    int largestRectangleArea(vector<int>& heights) {
        stack<int> h;
        stack<int> b;
        int maxa;
        int n = heights.size();
        h.push(heights[0]);
        b.push(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (!h.empty() && !b.empty() && h.top() < heights[i]) {
                h.push(heights[i]);
                b.push(i);
                continue;
            }
            if (!h.empty() && !b.empty() &&h.top() == heights[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            while (!h.empty() && !b.empty() && h.top() > heights[i]) {
                maxa = max(maxa, h.top() * (i - b.top()));
                h.pop();
                b.pop();
            }
            h.push(heights[i]);
            b.push(b.top());
        }
        while (!h.empty()) {
            maxa = max(maxa, (h.top() * (n - b.top())));
            h.pop();
            b.pop();
        }
        return maxa;
    } 
};
```

Comment: The last `while` doesn't check for `b.empty`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: You use uninitialized maxa in the comparisons. And possible access to the first element of the empty heights.